# Highcharts contextButton color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to custom Highchart's export button. I read on their doc that we can easily access to the buttons style with

`buttons: { contextButton: ... }`
but it seems that I only can modify the symbol and I want to change the background color of the button too.

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/X4HeH/1/) on JSFiddle.
As we can see, the symbol's color can be changed with `symbolStroke` option but how can I change the background ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change the theme node of the button. For example:

[Full Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f3cahrzn/)

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            backgroundColor: "white"
        },


        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }],

        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    symbolStroke: "red",
                    theme: {
            fill:"gray"
        }
                }
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Source: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.contextButton.theme

Answer (score 0):

If you work in styledMode, then add the following in your CSS file:

```
.highcharts-contextbutton {
  fill: blue;
}
```